# Calling Javascript On Someone Else's Site From Custom Browser

Tags: javascript, redirect, browser

I have a custom browser for kids that blocks a whole ton of sites, including blocking pop ups.

I would like to link to the **games** section of this [PEEP](http://www.peepandthebigwideworld.com/) site, but for some reason, when I copy/paste the [url](http://www.peepandthebigwideworld.com/games/) to the game page, it just redirects me to the home page.

I look at the source, and the onclick is set to "return gamesWin(this.href)". I see that javascript function in the source... so I would like to either:

1. Call that from my browser to redirect the user to the games page directly
2. Make a quick custom web page to redirect them to the game list

Are either of these possible? How/what should I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Games page is checking if the visit is coming from their website -- they check for the presence of the string `"peepand"`:

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf('peepand')==-1) {location.replace('../');
```

So, if you create a page at a location which has "peepand" somewhere in the path, or even in a query string parameter (`foo.html?peepand=`), a link on that page should work.

Note, however, that this can be discovered by the site admins, and they might introduce a better checking mechanism that won't be so easy to work around.

Comment: Of course, we found an alternate non-popup version of that page this morning, but thanks, I was curious about this.